# Passing argument 2 of sprintf makes pointer from integer without a cast. C warning

Tags: c, warnings

```
char temp_fname[OSCAR_MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN+1];
char temp_fname_len[2+1];
char temp_cdate[OSCAR_DATE_SIZE+1];
struct stat st;



   sprintf(temp_fname, OSCAR_MAX_FILE_MNAME_LEN+1, "%-30s", argv[i]);
   sprintf(temp_fname_len, 3, "%-2u", (int)strlen(argv[i]));
   sprintf(temp_cdate, OSCAR_DATE_SIZE+1, "%-12u", (unsigned int) st.st_ctime);
```

I've included stdio.h and string.h. What should I do to fix this? 
Please let me know if I need to add more information about the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a size argument to `sprintf` which does not expect one, use `snprintf` to pass a size argument.